# Is there any feature of ES 6 which can not be converted into ES 5 equivalent by any transpiler like Babel?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

Various transpilers are offering utilities to convert your ES6 code to ES5. Though ES6 involves lot of sugar coating features over ES5 but is there any feature of ES6 which can not be transpiled to ES5?

Comment: [http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find here the [official ES6 Specification](http://es6-features.org/). Every feature has its own ES5 translation.

The "new" features available with ES6 that cannot be transpiled in ES5 are :

- [Raw String Access](http://es6-features.org/#RawStringAccess)
- Some [extended literals](http://es6-features.org/#UnicodeStringRegExpLiteral)
- [Symbol Types](http://es6-features.org/#SymbolType) and [Global Symbols](http://es6-features.org/#GlobalSymbols)
- [Generator Matching](http://es6-features.org/#GeneratorMatching), [Control Flow](http://es6-features.org/#GeneratorControlFlow) and [Methods](http://es6-features.org/#GeneratorMethods)
- [Weak-Link Data-Structures](http://es6-features.org/#WeakLinkDataStructures)
- [Typed Arrays](http://es6-features.org/#TypedArrays)
- [Proxies](http://es6-features.org/#Proxying)
- [Collation](http://es6-features.org/#Collation)
- [Number Formatting](http://es6-features.org/#NumberFormatting)
- [Currency Formatting](http://es6-features.org/#CurrencyFormatting)
- [Date/Time Formatting](http://es6-features.org/#DateTimeFormatting)

Comment: So, Babel does not convert above mentioned ES6 features to ES5? OR does transpilers like babel do some work around?

Comment: What you linked to is not the official specification. It's just a site somebody built. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ is the official spec. Also, generators can be converted to ES5, it's just complicated: https://facebook.github.io/regenerator/ . Number and datetime formatting is implemented in https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/ .

Answer (score 0):

On this web-site http://es6-features.org/, there are ES6 features and their equivalent in ES5, or written that no equiavalent